# Redirect If URL Param Contains Specific Substring Value

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to use mod_rewrite to redirect users coming with a certain substring in their URL.

For example, `INBOUND_XXX34_MPEG`, if `34` is in the URL, I need to redirect to a different integer (i.e.: `INBOUND_XXX20_MPEG`)

Is this type fine tooth-combing possible with mod_rewrite?

**EDIT** what I have so far, but fails in testing:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*=\w*)34(.*)$ $120$2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it!

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} linkid=(.*)34(_.*)$
RewriteRule (.*) $1?linkid=%120%2 [R=301,L]
```

This will preserve URI, additional query params, and target the substring index.

Comment: Nice. Mark it as answered then. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what you really want but how about this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)INBOUND_XXX34_MPEG(.*)$ $1INBOUND_XXX20_MPEG$2
```

I do not know if the `XXX`is some can of variable thing?

Comment: The above example is a possible query string. All word segments are subject to change except of the `34`

Comment: In that cas, can you provide a bit more example? like does ALL URL with 34 get rewritten to the same pre/suffix but 20?